# How to identify starting values for constrOptim()?

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I'm using constrOptim() in R to estimate parameters of a model. I get the error that my target function has a result of length 0 instead 1. The problem can be the starting values I chose. I'm using R the first time and I'm not familiar with the constrOptim algorithm itself. Can somebody help me with the optimization?

my input:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('^GDAXI', src='yahoo', return.class='ts',from="2005-01-01", to="2015-01-31")
GDAXI.DE=GDAXI[ , "GDAXI.Close"]
log_r1=diff(log(GDAXI.DE[39:2575]))

sigma=matrix(nrow=length(log_r1)-1, ncol=1)
for(i in 2:length(log_r1))
{
sigma[i-1]=var(log_r1[1:i])
}

error=matrix(nrow=length(log_r1), ncol=1)
mu=mean(log_r1)
for(i in 1:length(log_r1))
{
error[i]=log_r1[i]-mu
}
```

the function i want to minimize:

```
LogLik=function(th)
{
input=garch(th)
sig=input
for(i in 1:length(sigma))
{
LL=(-1/2)*log(2*pi)-(1/2)*log(sig[i])-(1/2)*er[i]/sig[i]
}
}
```

the function calculating the input above:

```
sig=var(log_r1)
er=error
Sigma_garch=matrix(nrow=length(sigma), ncol=1)
garch=function(th)
{
omega.0=th[1]
alpha.0=th[2]
beta.0=th[3]
for(i in 1:length(sigma))
{
if(i==1)
{
  Sigma_ga=sig
}else
{
  Sigma_ga=Sigma_garch[i-1]
}
Sigma_garch[i]=omega.0+alpha.0*er[i]^2+beta.0*Sigma_ga 
}
return(Sigma_garch)
}
```

my constraints and optimization procedure:

```
ui=matrix(c(diag(1,3),c(0,(-1),(-1))),4,3, byrow = T)
ci=c(0.01,0,0,(-0.99))
theta=c(0.02,0.01,0.95)
est=constrOptim(c(0.02,0.01,0.95),LogLik, grad=NULL, ui,ci,hessian=FALSE)
```

the error I'm getting: `Error in optim(theta.old, fun, gradient, control = control, method = method,  :   Zielfunktion gibt Ergebnis der Länge 0 zurück, nicht Länge 1`.

Does somebody can tell me what can be the probleme here?

Answer (score 0):

Your target function, `LogLik`, doesnt return a value resulting in  `target function has a result of length 0 instead 1.`

```
LogLik=function(th)
{
input=garch(th)
sig=input
for(i in 1:length(sigma))
{
LL=(-1/2)*log(2*pi)-(1/2)*log(sig[i])-(1/2)*er[i]/sig[i]
}
return(LL)
}
```